# Overlaying a div on a cordova plugin

Tags: angularjs, cordova

I'm trying to develop an app in `cordova` that save videos with an aspect ratio `squared`.

What I want is to display a layer over [$cordovaCapture.captureVideo](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/capture/) that makes the user think it's recording in `1:1` so I can crop before I store it.

Do I have any way to make an overlaying on the camera?

Thanks in advice.